# Silverlight - DataContext, DataGrid, WCF and adding elements programatically with binding

Tags: wcf, silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-5.0

I'm pretty new to Silverlight.

I have a usercontrol with a datagrid and other form elements.
I'm trying to achieve binding programatically, loading the data from a WCF service.

this is what I have, I'm not sure how to actually make it work:

```
public class DepartmentObject
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Person> People { get; set; }
}    

public partial class DepartmentView : UserControl
{
    ObservableCollection<Person> LocalPeople { get; set; }
    Service1Client client = new Proj.ServiceReference1.Service1Client();

    public TemplateView(Guid departmentId)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        client.GetDeptCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            this.DataContext = e.Result; //DepartmentObject w/People member IEnumerable<Person>

            this.peopleList.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("People"));

            LocalPeople = new ObservableCollection<Person>(e.Result.People);
        };

        client.GetDeptAsync(departmentId);
    }


    private void Add_Person_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LocalPeople.Add(new Person() { Name = String.Format("Person [{0}]", LocalPeople.Count) });
    }
}
```

Now, I understand why it doesn't work - there's no "connection" between the observable collection and the data context, but what is the proper way of doing this?

`peopleList` is a DataGrid, which will have secondary binding when a person is selected.

I want to be able to hit "Save" eventually and get everything that changed in `DepartmentObject`.

I've gone through *a lot* of examples and all the SL 2-3-4 examples are different and confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether the e.Result is going to get persisted. The following should work though:

```
client.GetDeptCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
   LocalPeople = new ObservableCollection<Person>(e.Result.People);
   this.peopleList.DataContext = LocalPeople; //DepartmentObject w/People member IEnumerable<Person>
   this.peopleList.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("."));
};
```

Set a break point after LocalPeople has been assigned to make sure the collection isn't empty.

Comment: Thanks, it works and adding a new Person also works. What if I want to be able to edit and persist `DepartmentObject.Name` (or any additional properties) - what is the correct way to make the entire thing "observable"?

Comment: WCF Ria Services provides client side change tracking, all the way to persisting the data on the server-side.  It is reasonably capable.